# Drag finger from one button to another - want to un-trigger old button and trigger new button - Windows Store

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I am working on a windows store application and I want to be able to drag between buttons so that the originally pressed button becomes deactivated and the newly "dragged onto" button becomes activated but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have 2 Buttons inside a StackPanel and the events I have on them are:

- PointerPressed
- PointerEntered
- PointerReleased
- PointerExited
- PointerCanceled
- PointerCaptureLost

PointerPressed and PointerEntered share the same event handler and the rest (the "deactivation" events) share the same event handler.

If I press one button my "activated" event handler is triggered and if I drag off it my "deactivated" event handler is triggered but if I then drag onto the second button the "activated" event handler isn't triggered again.

Strangely, if I start by dragging from off the StackPanel onto one of the buttons the "activated" event handler is triggered. I assume that it is something to do with the internal pointer management stuff but can't seem to find a workaround.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get it to work how I want?

Thanks for your time.

**Edit**

Okay I've been researching some stuff and I've come across CapturePointer() and ReleasePointerCapture() but this seems to be broken - If I capture the pointer, when I take my finger off the screen, PointerReleased doesn't even get hit.

I've also realized why the "dragging from off the SP onto one of the buttons causes it to 'activate'" - this is because when a button is pressed it doesn't route its event but fires a Click event - meaning the same pointer cannot fire a PointerEntered event of another button, but if it starts outside a Button it will trigger PointerEntered.

This doesn't get me much further but it is a little extra info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Button is a bit unique in regard to mouse capture and how dragging away from it happens.  In your scenario I'm not sure if the event model around Button will work correctly for you.  On Button, when a pointer is depressed (mouse) it has capture until it is released.  This is not the same for touch where a press and drag away is different because in touch there isn't any explicit capture unless you create it.

So what you are hitting is going to be a slight conflict between mouse/touch interactions anyway using Button -- using some other UI element (not sure if you have a styled button) should get you what you want.

Comment: Ah yes, I've been reading around this just now and found out about the Click event stuff (as I put in my "edit") so I guess I should maybe just use a Rectangle and style it the same. How does changing what the button looks like OnPress, OnEnter and Normal work? Like how would I make a Rectangle do the same thing? Does it have to be done programmatically or can I do some fancy stuff with XAML and Visual Styles etc?

Comment: Okay I've done this now - I created my own control which is pretty much a button but just doesn't halt any of the "bubble-able" events such as OnPointerEntered/OnPointerExited.